# Can property evaluation be delayed or prevented in Ant?

Tags: tomcat, ant

I have a third-party Tomcat webapp which is configured with a .properties file processed with `ant` before deployment.

One property `DB.cache.dir` defines where some temporary files will be created. I would like this property to **evaluate** literally to `${java.io.tmpdir}`. The purpose being that when running the webapp will use the java.io.tmpdir value of the Tomcat running it rather than the value when it was configured by `ant`.

I tried to use `\` escape without luck and could not find an answer online.

Please advise.

```
# How to prevent evaluation for this property?
DB.cache.dir=${java.io.tmpdir}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign with another dollar sign, e.g.:

```
DB.cache.dir=$${java.io.tmpdir}
```

From [*Properties, Property Expansion, $$ Expansion*](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) in the Ant docs:

> In its default configuration Ant will expand the text $$ to a single $
> and suppress the normal property expansion mechanism for the text
> immediately following it, i.e., $${key} expands to ${key} and not
> value even though a property named key was defined and had the value
> value.

Comment: Many thanks. In my specific cas, a double escape with four `$` signs did tthe trick.